# How to store the data when fetching from API

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I create an application that retrieves data from a URL and display it. I'm a beginner and therefore I do not use Redux or other for the moment.

I managed to recover the data and display it on my application but I would like to use the local storage of the phone. I saw the examples for AsyncStorage on the documentation of the Expo website but I don't know how to adapt them to my code. In addition, do I have to display local storage data only when there is no internet connection? Or do I always still have to display them?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View, FlatList, Image, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {ListItem} from "react-native-elements";
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import PronosticsDetailsScreen from "../../screens/PronosticsDetailsScreen";
import AppConfig from "../../AppConfig";

class MontanteTab extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('https://myurl.com')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson
                }, function () {

                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
            )
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View>
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.dataSource}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                            renderItem={({item}) => (
                                <ListItem
                                    key={item.id}
                                    roundAvatar
                                    badge={{
                                        value: item.statut,
                                        textStyle: {color: '#fff'},
                                        containerStyle: {marginRight: 0, backgroundColor: item.couleur}
                                    }}
                                    avatar={<Image
                                        source={{uri: 'https://myurl.com/' + item.image}}
                                        style={{borderRadius: 50, height: 50, width: 50}}/>}
                                    title={item.competition}
                                    subtitle={item.equipe_domicile + ' - ' + item.equipe_exterieur}
                                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PronosticsDetails', {
                                        item,
                                    })}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT :

I tried this, but my data are not displayed :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View, FlatList, Image, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import axios from "axios";
import {ListItem} from "react-native-elements";
import {createAppContainer, createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import AppConfig from "../../AppConfig";
import Keys from "../../data/Constants/Storage";
import PronosticsDetailsScreen from "../../screens/PronosticsDetailsScreen";

class MontanteTab extends Component {

    state = {
        errors: null,
        isLoading: true,
        pronostics: [],
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const isConnected = true;

        if (isConnected) {
            await this.loadPronostics();
        }

        try {
            this.setState({pronostics: JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem(Keys.pronosticsMontante))});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    loadPronostics() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true, error: null});

        return axios.get(AppConfig.apiUrl + 'montante').then(async response => {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(Keys.pronosticsMontante, JSON.stringify(this.state.pronostics));
            this.setState({isLoading: false});
        }).catch(error => {
            this.setState({isLoading: false, error: error.response});
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading === true) {
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
            )
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <View>
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.pronostics}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                            renderItem={({item}) => (
                                <ListItem
                                    key={item.id}
                                    roundAvatar
                                    badge={{
                                        value: item.statut,
                                        textStyle: {color: '#fff'},
                                        containerStyle: {marginRight: 0, backgroundColor: item.couleur}
                                    }}
                                    avatar={<Image
                                        source={{uri: AppConfig.imagesPronosticsUrl + item.image}}
                                        style={{borderRadius: 50, height: 50, width: 50}}/>}
                                    title={item.competition}
                                    subtitle={item.equipe_domicile + ' - ' + item.equipe_exterieur}
                                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('PronosticsDetails', {
                                        item,
                                    })}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use React Native AsyncStorage for storing data to local storage of the device.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
```

Use this to save data

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

AsyncStorage accepts value as an only string, so you may need to use stringify() before setting the value to AsyncStorage

And to retrieve data use

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
```

> Code:

```
const KEY = 'USER_DATA'

let keyValue = { name: yogi }

AsyncStorage.setItem(KEY,keyValue);

AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY).then(asyncStorageRes => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(asyncStorageRes))
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When do I have to place this code in my code? I retrieve an array of objects, can I parse each object into JSON to store it in the AsyncStorage?

Comment: store the whole object or key and retrieve it .

Comment: I must put your code after this line : .then((responseJson) => { ?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a React Native project, I think `AsyncStorage` is what you're looking for.  You can set the value in your empty `setState` callback in `componentDidMount`.  If you only need to store the data at the end of a session, you can use `AppState` and set the value when nextState is background or inactive. 
Use `AsyncStorage.getItem()` when `AppState` or `nextState` is active. 
 https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on how frequently your listing data change,

if listing data is constant then you can store API response in local storage. and then display list data from local storage.

If listing data changing frequently, still you can use local storage. store data in local storage on API response.
On next time page load show data from local storage and also make API call to get latest data and on API response display data to list and also update in local storage.
Using this way user will not have to wait for API response.

For Storing Data use can use javascript syntax `localStorage.setItem('key', 'apiresponse')` and `localStorage.getItem('key')`

OR

can create Service class which will store API response in object, which can be also use in other files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I will use the AsyncStorage. I edited my post :)